# Cannot upload image using ajax in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to upload image using ajax in Codeigniter i have searched a lot but could not find the solution. I want to submit the form using jquery. Below is my code:
I am getting blank value when i retrieve value in controller from view by following code:

```
$file_names=$this->input->post('save_movie123');
```

View:

```
<html>
$(document.body).on('click', '.postbtn' ,function(e){
     $('#post_video_255').submit();
});


function sendVideoData()
{
      var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("#post_video_255"));

      $.ajax({
        url: "dashboard/do_upload",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form, 
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",           
        cache: false,
        contentType: false, 
        processData: false, 

        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
        },
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
            var data = XMLHttpRequest.responseText;
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    }).done(function() { 
        console.log('Done');

    }).fail(function() {       
        alert("fail!");
    });
}
</script>



<form name="post_video" id="post_video_255" method="post" onsubmit="return sendVideoData()">        
<span style="margin-left: 8px;">
<input type="file" name="save_movie123" id="movie123" />
<input type="button" class="postbtn" id="submit_movie_289" value="Upload Video File"/>
</form>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
function do_upload()
{
$file_names=$this->input->post('save_movie123');
$config['upload_path'] ='./uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png||jpeg';
$config['max_width'] = 1000;
$config['max_height'] = 1000;
$config['max_size'] = 200000;
$config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload($file_names);
}
```

Comment: you have any error in console.

Comment: @Niranjan N Raju  No i do not get any error nut ajax error part is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        csrf_test_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Radu But i have to pass other values with the image Can u please guide me to use code like above.

Comment: take a look at this: http://jerel.co/blog/2012/03/a-simple-solution-to-codeigniter-csrf-protection-and-ajax

Comment: also add this to your form:  enctype="multipart/form-data"